# Where is my syntax error in regards to formatted printing?

Tags: bash, shell, formatting

I'm currently working on an assignment for one of my classes and I have a bulk of the code finished but when I run it I'm getting this error:

> line 48: syntax error near unexpected token `%6.2f'

I've parsed through my code about a thousand times now and have switched things around in hopes it'll work, but I'm at a loss so I'm asking here.

This is my code:

```
file="./homeOfficeData.dat"
totElec=0
totHeat=0
totTele=0
totMorInt=0
totRent=0
totCityTaxes=0
totIns=0
totRepMain=0
totDepr=0
totMonth=0

echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
printf "%82s" "HOME OFFICE EXPENSES"
printf "\n%92s" "Report Date $(date)"
printf "\n%85s\n" "Prepared by: **********"
echo "........................................................................................................................................................."
printf "%s %13s %9s %11s %19s %6s %12s %11s %18s %21s %17s\n" "Month" "Electricity" "Heating" "Telephone" "Mortgage Interest" "Rent" "City Taxes" "Home Ins." "Repairs & Maint." "Depreciation (7.5%)" "Total Per Month"
echo "........................................................................................................................................................."

while IFS=, read -r elec1 heat2 tele3 morInt4 rent5 cityTaxes6 ins7 repMain8; do
totElec=$(echo "$totElec+$elec1" | bc -l)
totHeat=$(echo "$totHeat+$heat2" | bc -l)
totTele=$(echo "$totTele+$tele3" | bc -l)
totMorInt=$(echo "$totMorInt+$mortInt4" | bc -l)
totRent=$(echo "$totRent+$rent5" | bc -l)
totCityTaxes=$(echo "$totCityTaxes+$cityTaxes6" | bc -l)
totIns=$(echo "$totIns+$ins7" | bc -l)
totRepMain=$(echo "$totRepMain+$repMain8" | bc -l)
dep9=$(echo "$elec1+heat2+tele3+morInt4+rent5+cityTaxes6+ins7+repMain8" | bc -l)
depreciationValue=$(echo "$dep9*7.5/100" | bc -l)
totMonth=$(echo "$elec1+heat2+tele3+mortInt4+rent5+cityTaxes6+ins7+repMain8+dep9" | bc -l)

printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "January" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "February" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "March" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "April" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "May" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "June" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "July" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "August" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "September" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "October" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "November" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "December" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
done <"$file”
echo "........................................................................................................................................................."
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "Totals Paid" "$totElec" "$totHeat" "$totTele" "$totMorInt" "$totRent" "$totCityTaxes" "$totIns" "$totRepMain" "$depreciationValue" "$totMonth"

echo "Grand Total: $totMonth"
echo "Percentage: 8%           **This is the percentage of your home, exclusively used as the business office or space."
echo "Total Claim: $(echo "$totMonth*80/100");
```

This code is supposed to read data separated by commas in a file and print the data in a columned table, while doing arithmetic to come to a few conclusions. The data in the file looks like this:

```
178.67,140.67,120.00,780.00,1200.00,456.78,680.90,800.00
211.00,146.00,130.00,780.00,1200.00,691.00,680.90,0.00
234.45,140.00,115.78,780.00,1200.00,559.00,680.90,0.00
280.78,136.00,124.67,780.00,1200.00,601.00,710.45,900.00
298.45,100.00,120.67,780.00,1300.00,425.56,710.45,456.78
320.90,55.00,131.00,780.00,1300.00,638.00,710.45,39.89
340.90,45.89,143.89,780.00,1300.00,732.56,710.45,127.67
350.89,50.34,189.78,780.00,1300.00,623.67,731.34,0.00
349.45,57.67,170.56,780.00,1350.00,578.32,731.34,245.67
290.90,65.67,150.44,780.00,1350.00,497.67,731.34,0.00
245.90,79.89,130.34,780.00,1350.00,501.45,750.00,0.00
210.56,120.99,141.56,780.00,1350.00,510.56,750.00,325.11
```

And when run, the output should look like this...

[image]

I appreciate anyone that can help me out because I'm seriously pulling my hair out here. Every example this professor has given follows the syntax I've used and I just cannot find why I'm getting this error.

Comment: 1. You could use [tag:bash] *integer* capabilities: `declare -i totElec=0 totHeat=0...` , then`totElec+=elec1` (without dollar sgn) will simplify and may give some light...

Comment: 2. Test you code using `shellcheck`. You will read: ` SC1070 (error): Parsing stopped here. Mismatched keywords or invalid parentheses?`., and `SC1141 (error): Unexpected tokens after compound command. Bad redirection or missing ;/&&/||/|?
`

Comment: @F. Hauri -- I fixed the error but I still can't get the code to work.. not sure what the issue is but it's printing messy as hell. Probably just going to turn in what I have and hope my professor is able to figure it out (he usually doesn't offer feedback on anything we get wrong, so not sure how I'm supposed to learn! haha). Thanks for your help.

Comment: The close-quote in `done <"$file”` is a fancy unicode quote, which the shell will not recognize. Use only plain ASCII punctuation marks for shell syntax.

Comment: You may found a full sample script using bash's integer capabilities, here: [homeWordk](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/someHomeWork.sh.txt) (short and quick)

Comment: @uglyorgans after your comment, i took a deeper look at your script and edited my answer because your script is full of mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at syntax highlighting. line 46 `done <"$file”`
This character `”`is not that character `"`
`done <"$file"`

**EDIT:**
after  uglyorgans wrote in comments: I fixed the error but I still can't get the code to work, i took a deeper look

**mistakes:**
....................................................
here you define **morInt4**
`while IFS=, read -r elec1 heat2 tele3 morInt4`

here you use **mortInt4**

```
totMorInt=$(echo "$totMorInt+$mortInt4"
```

```
totMonth=$(echo "$elec1+heat2+tele3+mortInt4
```

**and you forgot the $ sign in some lines

$heat2 $tele3 $morInt4**
....................................................
`while IFS=, read -r elec1 heat2 tele3 morInt4 rent5 cityTaxes6 ins7 repMain8; do`
here you read each line from homeOfficeData.dat, which has 12 lines, probably for each month one line, then split it  in words with "," but print for each line 12 months from (jan-dec), printing 144 lines

```
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "January" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "February" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "March" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "April" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "May" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "June" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "July" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "August" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "September" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "October" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "November" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "December" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8"
```

........................................................
`echo "Total Claim: $(echo "$totMonth*80/100");`
this line contains 3 quotes and would lead to an error.
probably you mean
`echo "Total Claim: $(bc <<< $totMonth*80/100)";`
.......................................................

Although i would never write the code in this way, i think i can help with this, removing some errors from your code, but its your work!

```
file="./homeOfficeData.dat"
totElec=0
totHeat=0
totTele=0
totMorInt=0
totRent=0
totCityTaxes=0
totIns=0
totRepMain=0
totDepr=0
totMonth=0

declare -i month=0                         # actual month integer 0=jan, 11=dec
declare -a months
IFS=";" read -ra months <<< $(locale mon)  # build month array out of locale mon

echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
printf "%82s" "HOME OFFICE EXPENSES"
printf "\n%92s" "Report Date $(date)"
printf "\n%85s\n" "Prepared by: **********"
echo "........................................................................................................................................................."
printf "%s %13s %9s %11s %19s %6s %12s %11s %18s %21s %17s\n" "Month" "Electricity" "Heating" "Telephone" "Mortgage Interest" "Rent" "City Taxes" "Home Ins." "Repairs & Maint." "Depreciation (7.5%)" "Total Per Month"
echo "........................................................................................................................................................."

while IFS="," read -r elec1 heat2 tele3 morInt4 rent5 cityTaxes6 ins7 repMain8; do
   totElec=$(echo "$totElec+$elec1" | bc -l)
   totHeat=$(echo "$totHeat+$heat2" | bc -l)
   totTele=$(echo "$totTele+$tele3" | bc -l)
   totMorInt=$(echo "$totMorInt+$morInt4" | bc -l)
   totRent=$(echo "$totRent+$rent5" | bc -l)
   totCityTaxes=$(echo "$totCityTaxes+$cityTaxes6" | bc -l)
   totIns=$(echo "$totIns+$ins7" | bc -l)
   totRepMain=$(echo "$totRepMain+$repMain8" | bc -l)
   dep9=$(echo "$elec1+$heat2+$tele3+$morInt4+$rent5+$cityTaxes6+$ins7+$repMain8" | bc -l)
   depreciationValue=$(echo "$dep9*7.5/100" | bc -l)
   totMonth=$(echo "$elec1+$heat2+$tele3+$morInt4+$rent5+$cityTaxes6+$ins7+$repMain8+$dep9" | bc -l)

   printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "${months[month]}" "$elec1" "$heat2" "$tele3" "$morInt4" "$rent5" "$cityTaxes6" "$ins7" "$repMain8" 
   ((month++))
done <"$file"
echo "........................................................................................................................................................."
printf "%s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n" "Totals Paid" "$totElec" "$totHeat" "$totTele" "$totMorInt" "$totRent" "$totCityTaxes" "$totIns" "$totRepMain" "$depreciationValue" "$totMonth"

echo "Grand Total: $totMonth"
echo "Percentage: 8%           **This is the percentage of your home, exclusively used as the business office or space."
echo "Total Claim: $(bc <<< $totMonth*80/100)";
```